# unique count number on key in key-value pair except first line using shell script

Tags: shell

I have csv file like below one

```
5
1,a
2,4
1,a
1,a
2,9
```

how can i count unique keys(key is 1st column and value is 2nd column) in this above data except first line 
result example :

```
1,1
2,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short `awk` script will handle this without much effort. You essentially collect an array of all lines using the line itself as the index (which will give you the unique lines in the file). In the `END` rule, you can loop over the array, creating a second array using the first field (the text before the `','`) as the index creating an array with the number of times the first field occurs in a unique line in the file. You then just output the final array contents, e.g.

```
awk 'FNR>1 {                        # for 2nd record on
    a[$0]++                         # fill array using record as index
}
END {                               # in END rule
    for (i in a)                    # loop over values in a
        # use substing up to first ',' as index for b 
        b[substr(i,match(i,/^,/),1)]++
    for (i in b)                    # loop over values in b
        printf "%s,%s\n", i,b[i]    # output unique occurrences
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

You can simply paste at the command line with your values in `file` and receive the following:

```
$ awk 'FNR>1 {                        # for 2nd record on
>     a[$0]++                         # fill array using record as index
> }
> END {                               # in END rule
>     for (i in a)                    # loop over values in a
>         # use substing up to first ',' as index for b
>         b[substr(i,match(i,/^,/),1)]++
>     for (i in b)                    # loop over values in b
>         printf "%s,%s\n", i,b[i]    # output unique occurrences
> }' file
1,1
2,2
```

Answer (score 0):

For task like the above, possible to combine standard tools

```
cat file.txt |
   tail +2 |
   sort --unique |
   cut --delimiter=, --fields=1 |
   uniq --count |
   awk '{ printf "%d,%s\n", $2, $1 }'
```

Or Single Line

```
(tail +2 | sort -u | cut -d, -f1 | uniq -c | awk '{ printf "%d,%s\n", $2, $1 }) < file.txt
```

Comment: I would find it more natural to write it as `tail +2 file.txt | sort ....`. No need for either the `cat` process or the additional subshell in your second solution.